# OpenRewrite recipe to migrate Joda to Java 8 time?

Tags: jodatime, java-time, openrewrite

Since Java 8, Joda time has been replaced by the standard java.time APIs. Is there a OpenRewrite recipe that does that automatically? Especially in a big codebase, the task can prove tedious to be done by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such recipe yet, but support is being tracked in this issue: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-migrate-java/issues/234

You can follow along or even help out there.